# commandfield put title attribute on images button

Tags: asp.net, commandfield

Is possible to set the title attibute on the image buttons of a commandfield?

```
 <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Image"  ShowEditButton="True" 
                                DeleteImageUrl="images/BPAnn.gif" EditImageUrl="images/edit.gif" DeleteText="Elimina" EditText="Modifica"
                                UpdateImageUrl="images/apply.gif" CancelImageUrl="images/undo.gif" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say Title do you mean HeaderText???

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" HeaderText="Testing" />
```

Comment: sorry i want the tooltip on the button

Answer (score 0):

If You want Tooltip my suggestion is to convert CommandField to TemplateField.

In Template field you have more options available.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs this you can do this for any command. Here it is done for the delete:

```
<asp:CommandField DeleteText="<i aria-hidden='true' title='Delete Role' class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'>" ShowDeleteButton="True"/>
```